# How can I add more points with an average values of elevation of the nearby points - QGIS

Tags: average, interpolation, arcgis, qgis, elevation

Hi I have a DEM that is low in resolution and want to estimate the elevation values of the spaces between the points. I understand that this is not ideal but this to put the data in machine learning software and make a better spatial match of the elevation data and other data used. I can use QGIS or ArcGIS to do that if you can guide.
Thanks
ZS

Answer (score 0):

A DEM is a a raster.  There are no points, however you can create a center point for each  DEM raster cell using the arcmap tool "Raster to Points" if the raster is large, this could take a long time.

At this point there are multiple algorithms that can be used to interpolate between the points.  Look into surfaces.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/commonly-used-tools/surface-creation-and-analysis.htm

From above link: "There are several ways to create surfaces, including interpolating values stored at measured point locations, interpolating a surface of the density of a given phenomenon or feature type from the numbers of features in an area, deriving surfaces of distance (or direction) from a feature or features, or deriving a surface from another surface (slope raster from elevation)."

Once you decide what interpolation you want to apply and you create an interpolated raster you can export it to a new DEM with a higher resolution.

In the future you would probably get better/facter results posting this question to the GIS Stack exchange. https://gis.stackexchange.com/